# Can wpa_supplicant be used to scan wireless networks in a way similar to iwlist scanning option?

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

Being completely unknowledgeable in the following, I am trying to scan wifi networks in linux. The best I could find was iwlist from [wireless tools](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/wireless-tools), but I came across some remarks ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59088125/1219280)) stating that wireless tools is obsolete and wpa_supplicant should be used instead.

iwlist scanning option fitted my needs. How do I query wireless networks using wpa_supplicant, in a similar fashion ? The [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/5/wpa_supplicant.conf) say you need to define a .conf file, but as far as I understand you define beforehand the networks (ssids) you are interested in scanning/working with - which is not what I am after.

Can wpa_supplicant be used to do a similar job as iwlist scanning, out of the box ?

Answer (score 4):

> stating that wireless tools is obsolete and wpa_supplicant should be used instead.

Well, `iwlist` is indeed obsolete, but it has been replaced by `iw`. You can use `iw wlan0 scan dump` to show the existing scan, and `iw wlan0 scan` to trigger a new scan.

> Can wpa_supplicant be used to do a similar job as iwlist scanning

You can use `wpa_cli` and then issue `scan` to do a scan, and `scan_results` to see the results.

However, `wpa_supplicant` is one level above `iw`; it is mainly for authentication. That you can also do scans is more a side issue.

Also have a look at `aerodump-ng` if you want to do WLAN scanning (this tool doesn't use the inbuilt scan functionality, but does its own channel hopping, and also identifies clients, not only APs).

---

> the whole story starts in the desire to read AP beacons in linux

If that's your ultimate goal (and you should have mentioned this in the question. Please also read up on [XY questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), then the simplest way is to put the interface into monitor mode, and read the AP beacons. All internal scans will give you the *stored results* of the received beacons, and not the beacons themselves.

You can try this out with Wireshark, see e.g. [here](https://kasiviswanathanblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/capture-beacon-frames/) (first google result), and then use it in your own programs, if so desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guidance. What do you mean by "not only access points, but also clients" ? What is the meaning of identifying a client in a wlan scan ? I could know all MACs connected to the given AP/SSID/BSSID ?

Comment: What you can see with `iw` are the internal driver/firmware lists, which means all APs in range when the interface is in client mode, and all connected clients when the interface is in AP mode. Aircrack-ng is a hacking tool that doesn't use those internal lists, but reads all transmitted data by putting the interface into monitor mode. So you will catch all MACs **transmitting** something, whether it's AP beacons, are actual traffic. This is typically a subset of all clients. You will also catch clients looking for hidden APs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt and detailed help. Highly appreciated. I posted several questions in the last 24 hours, all ultimately resulting from this, and me trying to figure out alternatives/how to overcome it. I will take a look at Aircrack-ng, indeed, the whole story starts in the desire to read AP beacons in linux, and iwlist scanning looked the most adequate option.

Comment: As a follow up, the best I got so far with iw was running `iw dev [my wlan interface name] scan dump -v` (tried iw station dump command as well, to no avail). I am looking at [iw's source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jberg/iw.git) , and it looks it does not use `ioctl` at all, as opposed to `iwlist`? This is interesting.

Comment: Posted [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/666266/433212) as well, in case you have an answer there as well.