# Reading wireless beacon frames in linux

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant, iw

I am completely new to networks, and need to find a way to read wireless networks beacon frames data. I did so for windows, using Win32 wlanapi, now need to do the same for linux.

I have been trying to port iwlist scanning functionality (which seems to parse bssds beacon frames good enough for me) into a c# app, but without success.

As a last shot, I would like to inquire about which other tools in linux do read beacon frames. I prefer reading the frames following the type-length-value structure myself, rather than have it parsed to string.

What are the options out there for this ? could you please share an example call for such a tool ?

I have been playing (or trying) with:

1. iwlist scanning
2. iw dev [interface name] scan dump -v (does not seem to read beacon frames, at least not as iwlist scanning)
3. wpa_supplicant - not managed to do so, if possible at all
4. libpcap (not tried yet)

Remark: UI tools are not suitable. My goal is to have a C# app running at regular intervals reading beacon frames and extracting info from them.

Do ultimately all options rely on communicating with [linux 80211 driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/80211/index.html)? Meaning writing a C program that interfaces the driver a good option, so not to rely in anything else?

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35535377/3554119), option 3: Use monitor mode on the wireless interface with libpcap. As I wrote in the other answer: You can try it out with wireshark, which does exactly that. Handy to create some capture files with known content for testing your program.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21459419/1219280) helps, after I ended up understanding that the starting point is [linux 80211 driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/80211/index.html).

Comment: No, you don't have to bother with the driver. In particular you don't have to touch anything kernel-related. You just put the interface into monitor mode, use the userland-library pcap, and you get the beacon frames (and all other frames, too). You just need to parse them. And if you try it in Wireshark first, you'll **see** how to parse them.